# How to parralize vector operations

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I want to add two vectors parrallel and use mpi4py to do that. 
But I am not very familliar with mip4py so my question is if this code below is already parallaized? When i use the expression `mpirun -n 3 python3 Übung2.py`does 3 stands for the number of workers?

here is my code:

```
na=10**6
va = np.random.rand(na,1)
vaa = np.random.rand(na,1)

from mpi4py import MPI
import time

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
# master process
sume=0
VA=[]
if rank == 0:
    start_time = time.time()


    # master process sends data to worker processes by
    # going through the ranks of all worker processes
    for i in range(1, size):
        VA.append(va+vaa)
        comm.send(VA, dest=i, tag=i)
        print(VA)
        #print('Process {} sent data:'.format(rank), data)
        sume = sume + (time.time() - start_time)


# worker processes
else:
    # each worker process receives data from master process
    data = comm.recv(source=0, tag=rank)
    #print('Process {} received data:'.format(rank), data)

print(sume)
```

Thank you

Comment: the canonical MPI way is to scatter your two vectors, sum the two (sub)vectors on each rank and then gather the (sub)vectors into the result.

Comment: I thought about that too. So you mean, each line and then store it in result? I could do it with for loop I think but i have no idead on how to use it with mpi

Comment: the idea is to divide the vectors in small chunks so each task can work on smaller (sub)vectors in parallel. feel free to implement your solution with send/recv if you do not want to use scatter/gather.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to do that? That would be great

Comment: I edited the code to what i tried